# How to run a macro when a cell updates through refreshing of data from web?

Tags: excel, vba

When the column is refreshing nothing is happening but when I go to the cell and change the value then it is changing.

I want when cells update through refresh it should run.

The column updates but the code doesn't trigger the macro.

Also tried `Worksheet_Calculate()`.

The column is linked with online stock data from NSE website.

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("B:B")) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Cell Value Changed"
        Call MyMacro()
    End If
End Sub
```

On internet just told to use `Worksheet_Calculate()`.

[image: Screensht]

Also if trying to update the cell which is equal to a cell in `Range("B:B")`, the value changes but macro doesn't trigger.

Comment: They are updating from web query
the data is from nseindia.com and I am doing it `From Web` under `DATA` section

Comment: If you're working with a QueryTable, then you may need to do something like this and add an event-handler for it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36342211/1467082

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe give this a try by using `Workbook_SheetChange` instead of `Worksheet_Change`

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("B:B")) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Cell Value Changed"
        Call MyMacro()
    End If
End Sub
```

Note that you need to put your code in `ThisWorkbook` and not your module

[image]

**Edit :** to test the Answer :

```
Sub TryMe()
For i = 1 To 100
Cells(2, 2).Value = i
Next 
End Sub
```

`TryMe` Should be added inside a module like below

[image]

`Workbook_SheetChange` hould be added inside `ThisWorkbook` like below

[image]

When we execute test module we should have stuff like this:

[image]
[image]
 and so on..

**EDIT 2 If Value are changed by formula :**

Give this a try :

This code should be placed in the sheet you are using (in my exemple Sheet1)

[image]

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("B:B")
    If Not Intersect(rng, Range("B:B")) Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Cell Value Changed"
    End If
End Sub
```

In a Module execute this code once :

```
Sub TryMe()

ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic

End Sub
```

then this should work

Answer (score 0):

You can use events of QueryTable object behind the table linked to a web source. To do that, you first need to create a class module. Let's call it `clsQryTebleEvents`. In that module place a `WithEvents` variable of type `Excel.QueryTable` and set it to the `QueryTable` for which you want to capture events. Here's the code for `clsQryTableEvents`:

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents qryTable As Excel.QueryTable

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    'QueryTable connected to a webpage is on Sheet1, and it's the only table on that sheet, so we can access it with ListObjects(1)
    Set qryTable = Sheet1.ListObjects(1).QueryTable
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    'Free Memory
    Set qryTable = Nothing
End Sub

'You can use other events as well
Private Sub qryTable_BeforeRefresh(Cancel As Boolean)
    MsgBox "Refresh is about to start!", vbInformation
End Sub
```

Next, you need to initialize a variable of this class. You can declare a `Public` variable inside a standard module and the use Workbook_Open event to instantiate it. Code in a standard module:

```
Option Explicit

Public objQryTable As clsQryTableEvents
```

Code in `ThisWorkbook`:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set objQryTable = New clsQryTableEvents
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    'Free memory
    Set objQryTable = Nothing
End Sub
```

All done! Next time you open the workbook, the `objQryTable` will be initialised and will start listening to refresh events.